# How to create a Racket mutable array from a C pointer to modify an OpenCV image?

Tags: arrays, opencv, lisp, racket, ffi

I am playing around with these [OpenCV bindings for Racket](https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/package/opencv), and I would like to be able to access the pixel values as an array, mostly so I can use row-column indexing. The examples only show how to call high-level OpenCV functions, and then accessing the raw data is only shown by a low-level access to a [bytestring](https://github.com/oetr/racket-opencv/blob/8124eb6b620769137656547e83f9d9587ab37c23/tutorials/03_imgproc/SimpleImageProcessing.rkt#L63).

It all works great, I was quite impressed. For some applications, thought, we should be able to do some pixel-by-pixel processing, ideally utilizing whatever is the native multidimensional array object in Racket, which seems to be `math:array`. The question is how to create this mutable array from the `IplImage` object.

I was able to run the bytestring example, which is not ideal already because it wouldn't support other types like float. The following piece of code works creating a `cvector` out of the pointer to the image data:

```
(define xx (make-cvector* (IplImage-imageData frame) ffi:_uint8 307200))
(cvector-set! xx ii 255)
(set! ii (ii . + . 1) )
```

This paints a pixel moving at each frame inside a loop... This works. Now I would like to create an array out of this `cvector`. I came up with the following code:

```
(define (image->array image)
  (let ([data
         (make-cvector* (IplImage-imageData image)
                        ffi:_uint8
                        (IplImage-imageSize image))]
        [shape (vector (IplImage-height image) (IplImage-width image))])
    (array->mutable-array (list->array
                           shape
                           (cvector->list data)))))
```

This apparently works for reading though not for writing back. How do I make it actually mutable? And are there any performance concerns here? Is `cvector->list` perhaps copying all the data into a new Racket list? How do I create a Racket vector object that can be used by `math:array`?

Comment: what do you mean by "wouldn't support...float"? can you give an example of what you'd like to do with floats?

Comment: `cvector->list` will copy the vector's contents.  `list->array` will copy them again, and `array->mutable-array` will make one more copy.  If you want accessors which will modify the bits of the original array, treating it as a two-dimensional object, I suspect you need to write them.

Comment: @adatzer Many applications represent images with larger depths than 8 bits, and also both fixed-point and floating-point types. OpenCV supports many such types, not to mention the channels.

Comment: @tfb well, the job of handling the dimensions is being done by the array functions, they just don't seem to accept a cvector instead of a vector, what would I need to implement this seemingly simple interface while preventing copies?

Comment: As I said, you probably need to write them: `math/array` is very definitely not what you want for this, as these arrays expect to manage their own storage if they are mutable.

Comment: Any specific array operations you're interested in? As already mentioned, using `math/array` won't work, since implementation is not sufficiently generic to operate on a different representation. If it's just a matter of accessing with row/col, then you could probably write a few macros that convert to the underlying cvector operation?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does indeed return a mutable-array.  Just that it works only for greyscale images, since `list->array` expects a list of length (* width height), while the `cvector->list` returns a list of length (* width height channels).  Going all the way: cpointer >> cvector >> list >> immutable-array >> mutable-array just to have row-column indexing seems a bit too much, since you could define a function to "simulate" the access style you want.

For the performance concerns, see this StackOverflow question[1] (by the creator of racket-opencv), which explains the reasoning behind bytestrings and the IplImage-data function. You already mentioned that bytestrings are not ideal for you, but still, even if you have to go towards vectors (or math/array), try also the way: cpointer >> bytestring >> list >> vector  (faster in my machine).

[1] [Fast array access using Racket FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491047/fast-array-access-using-racket-ffi)

Comment: Well I certainly don't _want_ to have a lot of trouble. I want to reuse existing functions built on top of arrays, using cvectors as a back-end. I'm looking for the simplest way to do it, or figuring out how to create a vector from a cvector of any type. By the way, (mutable-array (immutable-array ...)) is just what I understand is the normal way to create an immutable array in Racket, and an obviously simple operation to abstract, not the real problem here.